# How can I get the first date and the last date from the ClosedRange<Date>?

Tags: swiftui

How can I get the first date and the last date from the ClosedRange? I tried using myDateRange.First, but it give me an error saying

```
Referencing property 'first' on 'ClosedRange' requires that 'Date' conform to 'Strideable'
```

Here is what I have:

```
@State private var myDateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date>? = nil
           
VStack {
            MultiDatePicker(sampleDateClosedRange: self.$myDateClosedRange)
            if let myDateRange = myDateClosedRange {
                Text("\(myDateRange)").padding()
                //Print(myDateRange.First)
                    
             } else {
                    Text("Select two dates").padding()
             }
  
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `upperBound` and `lowerBound`.

```
let dateRange : ClosedRange<Date> = Date()...Date().addingTimeInterval(60)

dateRange.upperBound
dateRange.lowerBound
```